# Access Denied for file; can't view/edit/delete file even after taking ownership

Tags: windows, command-line, permissions, icacls

I have a set of Android Studio files that I cannot figure out how to "take" ownership of.

I initially tried via the windows GUI prompt (right click -> security tab -> advanced button -> owner tab -> edit -> selected myself as the owner), which seems to be successful, at least from what the GUI is telling me.

I then tried to take ownership with takeown and icacls

```
takeown /F <filename>

icacls <filename> /grant %username%:F
```

Which again did not work.

Next I tried running a cmd shell as SYSTEM via psexec

```
psexec -i -s cmd.exe
```

This also failed. Finally I rebooted my box into a live Linux environment (SystemRescueCD) and mounted my drive. Even from that environment, not only could i not copy the file, but I still couldn't view it (I got a permission denied error).

I'm out of ideas as to what to do next, so if you can think of anything, please let me know.